# Plex media server, media location

Tags: 16.04, permissions, plex

I have installed plex media server `plexmediaserver_1.1.3.2700-6f64a8d_amd64.deb` on Ubuntu Desktop 16.04LTS 64bit. The web app works when I place media in `/var/lib/plexmediaserver` as per the default settings. However it doesn't work if I place media in my own folder `/home/matt/PLEX` Or if I set the path to an external hard drive. I'm not sure if this is a permissions issue, or if it's a plex settings issue, or how I would correct either issue.

Comment: issue the command `ls -l /home/matt` and [edit] your question to include the PLEX line that starts with d so we can examine the permissions for you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your home directory `~/` and the directory where you have your media set have the read and execute permission.

You can set this, for the areas you have specified for your files with:

```
$ chmod go+x /home/matt
$ chmod go+xr /home/matt/PLEX
```

Also make sure your media has the `go+r` permission.

You can do the latter for all the files in your media area with:

```
$ chmod -R go+r /home/matt/PLEX
```

Answer (score 1):

Latest way of changing the database location for **systemd based systems** is explained here

https://forums.plex.tv/t/customizing-your-plex-configuration/205443

using

```
/etc/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service.d/override.conf
```

still works in 20.04

Comment: Can you include the steps here to avoid the answer becoming useless if the link breaks in the future?